# Login with Linkedin shows error "The Application is disabled"

Tags: reactjs, oauth-2.0, linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I'm integrating login with LinkedIn in react using react-linkedin-login-oauth2. But when clicking on the login button it shows the error in the linkedin popup as "The application is disabled". I've searched for the solutions on google but didn't find any. Can anyone help me to know that:

Q1) When LinkedIn throws this error - "The Applications is disabled"

Q2) How can we resolve this and make it work?

[image: error]